# Recursive sum of a list in subgroups

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that gets a list of numbers and variable "v", this function should return a list all subgroups of the list that sums "v" without repeating

Example: if list = [2,3,5,6,8,9,1] and v = 11 it should return [[9,2], [8,3], [5,6], [2,3,5,1], [8,2,1], [6,3,2]]

Edit: the numbers in list are positives and v number isn't going to be much bigger than the sum in list

I've tried doing splits of the list and making it doubly linked list, and then counting the subgroups, but I don't really get to the answer.

This one to go through the list and then trying to extract the items, but I don't really know how to do it

```
    def traverse(self, head):
        if (head == None):
            return
        current_node = head
        count = 1
        while (current_node):
            count += 1
            current_node = current_node.next
        return count
```

Comment: Looks like dynamic programming related question

Comment: (1) Are the numbers guaranteed to be positive? (2) Can variable `v` be much bigger than the length of the list, or is it guaranteed to be not-too-big?

Comment: Here is a bruteforce solution using [itertools recipe `powerset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes): `def subsets_with_sum(l, v): for subset in powerset(l): if sum(subset) == v: yield subset`. Example: `print(list(subsets_with_sum([1,1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10],10)))` will print `[(10,), (1, 9), (1, 9), (4, 6), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5), (1, 1, 2, 6), (1, 1, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)]`

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot use itertools

Comment: @Yslid Even if you have a homework that asks you to code the function without using itertools, it's still a good idea to write a second version using itertools. Then you can test your code by checking that both versions produce the same output.

Comment: (Note that two different versions might easily produce the same combinations but probably not in the same order, so use `sorted` to compare their output)

Comment: Also, if this is homework for a particular class, it would be great to tell us what kind of concepts have been covered in that class. For instance, @funnydman mentioned dynamic programming. Do you know what that is? Also, I notice you did not answer the two questions I asked in my first comment.